# Reactjs multiple conditional classes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to reactjs - looking to add some conditional class that come into action on the 3rd and 4th item in a loop

```
<div className={'medium-20 large-12 columns' + (index === 3 ? 'medium-push-10' : null)}>

if index 3 -- medium-push-10
if index 4 -- medium-pull-10
```

Comment: You could add to the ternary as mentioned in the answer.  Or, if you're testing several conditions, why not just add a new function that returns the desired class? <div className={ this.giveMeMyClass(index) }

Comment: That's a good idea too - well - take a peak at the concept in the comment to that answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ReactJS conditional component display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45503374/reactjs-conditional-component-display)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a quick solution you can add another Conditional Operator inside the second result of the first Conditional Operator.

```
<div className={'medium-20 large-12 columns' + (index === 3 ? ' medium-push-10' : index === 4 ? ' medium-pull-10' : '')}>
```

Don't go to far with this however, otherwise your code will soon be unreadable.

Comment: - Why do you advise caution.

Comment: to really enhance this -- I suppose if there are not enough items on the very last row -- so in an ipad view - where its 3 items per row -- and lets say the last row only has 2 items - that's where the medium-push-10 comes in

Comment: I've changed it to just use '' instead of null otherwise you create a null class - <div className={'medium-20 large-12 columns' + (index === 3 ? ' medium-push-10 ' : index === 4 ? ' medium-push-10 ' : '')}>

Comment: @TheOldCounty, if you go to far with this (Condition inside Condition inside Condition inside.... ), it will be very difficult to understand your code in the future. A better solution would be to create a function `getIndexClass(index)` where you use the Switch Statement and return the correct class based on the index parameter. Then your JSX can look like this: `<div className={'medium-20 large-12 columns' + this.getIndexClass(index)}>`
Yes, you are right. It adds null to the class when returning null. I've edited my answer with your suggestion.

Comment: Yeah - ok - ideally this needs to be a modulas - like index % 3 -- index % 4 -- thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dynamic-class-list) npm package. It automatically handles everything (string,array,objects,functions,null,undefined) and has options for static and conditional classes based on a variables with a simple syntax. All in 1kb.

```
// Support for string arguments
getClassNames('class1', 'class2');

// support for Object
getClassNames({class1: true, class2 : false});

// support for all type of data
getClassNames('class1', 'class2', ['class3', 'class4'], { 
    class5 : function() { return false; },
    class6 : function() { return true; }
});
// "class1 class2 class3 class4 class6"

<div className={getClassNames('show',{class1: true, class2 : false})} />
// "show class1"
```